# Getting Information About Deleted Item from GetListItemChangesSinceToken

Tags: web-services, caml-query, synchronisation

When calling `GetListItemChangesSinceToken`, and processing deletions, the data returned looks like this;

```
<Changes LastChangeToken="1;3;2e5fae54-20c4-4a9f-8e40-ae11784ee547;634873557043070000;106627" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <Id ChangeType="Delete" UniqueId="{BAD6C7BF-D874-4213-8DEA-6414846A8DA8}">55</Id>
</Changes>
```

For my application, I need to know whether this was a folder or a file. The info above is obviously not enough to go off, so I'm wondering is there any way to coerce SharePoint into returning this data?

I've tried using ViewFields as follows;

```
viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><FieldRef Name='ID' />";
```

But it still only returns the same XML as before.

Is there any other way to get this info from SharePoint?

Comment: McAtackney, see if [Using Change Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447511.aspx) is of some help!

Comment: Hi @ArsalanAdamKhatri, I'm constrained to using the web services unfortunately, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you seek (object type) is not kept in the ChangesLog database, so once the item itself is removed from the tables I doubt there is a way to obtain it.

In the ChangesDB you would have the Item's name and ID, that's about it IIRC. See [Retrieving events from SharePoint’s ChangeLog](http://spdynamite.net/2011/02/retrieving-events-from-sharepoints-changelog/)

Comment: Thanks @Louis - that's a shame. I'll have to adapt my application to account for this. Thanks for the info.